# How to fix a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java

I'm deploying a Java web application. But, the `ansj` package doesn't work normally when deployed using Tomcat. Strangely, it works well when running locally.

How can I fix the problem?

#### Java

```
public static boolean isSimilarity(String doc1, String doc2) {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    String[] page1 = NlpAnalysis.parse(doc1).toString().split(",");
    String[] page2 = NlpAnalysis.parse(doc2).toString().split(",");
    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();
    set1.addAll(Arrays.asList(page1));
    set2.addAll(Arrays.asList(page2));
    double or = 0;
    result.addAll(set1);
    result.retainAll(set2);
    or = (double) result.size() / set1.size();
    return or > 0.95;
}


31-Mar-2019 17:44:16.075 严重 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [testServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.nlpcn.commons.lang.util.logging.LogFactory.getLog()Lorg/nlpcn/commons/lang/util/logging/Log;
    at org.ansj.library.DicLibrary.<clinit>(DicLibrary.java:23)
    at org.ansj.splitWord.Analysis.<init>(Analysis.java:64)
    at org.ansj.splitWord.analysis.NlpAnalysis.<init>(NlpAnalysis.java:258)
    at org.ansj.splitWord.analysis.NlpAnalysis.parse(NlpAnalysis.java:266)
    at services.esti.Service.isSimilarity(Service.java:32)
    at services.esti.Service.incrementNum(Service.java:59)
    at services.esti.Service.getTotalPageNum(Service.java:71)
    at services.esti.Walker.getPageNum(Walker.java:208)
    at services.esti.StartTest.threadTest(StartTest.java:49)
    at api.estimate.testServlet.doGet(testServlet.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at
```

Below is my related pom.xml:

I don't see any conflicts in the jars and dependencies. I have been staying with the problem for several days.

#### xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cufe</groupId>
    <artifactId>dc-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2-b02</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <!--compatible with mysql8.0-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--HtmlUnit(headless web browser)-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.33</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ansj/ansj_seg -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ansj</groupId>
            <artifactId>ansj_seg</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.xml</include>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                    <include>*.txt</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Below is the mvn tree of all the dependencies:

#### Java

```
--------------------------< com.cufe:dc-web >---------------------------
[INFO] Building dc-web 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ dc-web ---
[INFO] com.cufe:dc-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.2-b02:provided
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:jar:2.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-cssparser:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
[INFO] +- org.ansj:ansj_seg:jar:5.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.nlpcn:nlp-lang:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.11.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:7.7.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:7.7.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:7.7.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:7.7.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.467 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-01T12:31:00+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is this maven project ? If yes can you please update question with `pom.xml`

Comment: Normally if a project runs properly in the local environment and with errors somewhere else then it's a good idea to check the involved libraries and dependencies. Something is obviously missing.

Comment: It's the typical error you get when multiple versions of the same lib are used or imported.

Comment: ... wow, you added the single dependency to the lib ... but, you have other dependencies as well as those have transitive dependencies. Do `mvn dependency:tree` and you'll see which other lib is importing a different version of the logging lib

Comment: I feel so helpless,I have beening staying with this error for several days,but I don't find any ideas that efficient.Who can help me,I would very appreciate of that.

Answer (score 1):

Finally,I found the cause of the bug by myself,hhhhhh.
That's surely because of conflict of jars.But it's not the common case.
In our project, there are already three external jars created by my teammates.Yes,they use the class org.nlpcn.commons.lang.util.logging.LogFactory in their jars.So there exists conflict.That's it.I will solve the problem by creating my own jar in avoid of conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try something like this:

add a maven dependecy

```
<!-- same dependency as used in htmlunit, try to remove after its working -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>  
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Than create 2 Files in /src/main/resources

**commons-logging.properties**

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
log4j.configuration=log4j.properties
```

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA, NTEventLog

#Console Appender
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

In this case your commons logging is using log4j.
Perhaps this helps.

Or you can try excluding commons-logging:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.33</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and add an another your preferred logging lib

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious answer! I tried both of them but it seems that it doesn't work.It still reports that error.

Comment: Again I tried,but the error info appears again.I almost despair of it...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i made a mistake ...pls. try to exclude once again ... :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.33</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: My guess is there are two versions of commons-logging that are not compatible. One from htmlunit and one that comes from Tomcat. I would say excluding the one from htmlunit should do the trick.

Comment: I think it's quite reasonable!

Comment: I appreciate it very much,but it seems not this reason.I think there maybe somthing wrong with the path.